# Assert Soft issue since 4.8.11

Tags: z3

I get an unexpected result from this optimization program.

I would expect the optimizer to throw out assertion "one" and keep "two" by setting a to 5 or less.  4.11.2 on the command-line sets a=5 and b=5. But when I run the Java program under 4.11.2, it sets a=6 and b=6 and throws out assertion "two."

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I believe it runs ok on 4.8.11, where it sets a=b=0.

```
(set-option :produce-unsat-cores true)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-assertions true)

(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)

(assert-soft (! (> a 10) :named one) :weight 10)
(assert-soft (! (< a 6) :named two) :weight 5)

; force "one" false
(assert (! (< b 8) :named three))
(assert (! (= a b) :named four))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var example = new Main.Example();
        example.run();
    }

    public static class Example {
        Map<String, String> options = Map.of(
                "auto_config", "false",
                "proof", "false",
                "model", "true",
                "unsat_core", "true"
        );

        Context z3 = new Context(options);

        public void run() {

            var a = z3.mkIntConst("a");
            var b = z3.mkIntConst("b");

            var opt = z3.mkOptimize();
            var trackers = new LinkedList<BoolExpr>();

            trackers.add(assertSoft(opt, z3.mkGt(a, z3.mkInt(10)), "one", 10, "default"));
            trackers.add(assertSoft(opt, z3.mkLt(a, z3.mkInt(6)), "two", 5, "default"));
            trackers.add(assertHard(opt, z3.mkLt(b, z3.mkInt(8)), "three"));
            trackers.add(assertHard(opt, z3.mkEq(a, b), "four"));

            var status = opt.Check();
            System.out.println("Z3 ver: " + Version.getFullVersion());
            System.out.println("Status: " + status);

            var model = opt.getModel();
            System.out.println("a = " + model.getConstInterp(a));
            System.out.println("b = " + model.getConstInterp(b));

            System.out.println("assertion one   = " + getBool(model, trackers.get(0)));
            System.out.println("assertion two   = " + getBool(model, trackers.get(1)));
            System.out.println("assertion three = " + getBool(model, trackers.get(2)));
            System.out.println("assertion four  = " + getBool(model, trackers.get(3)));
        }

        private String getBool(Model model, BoolExpr expr) {
            var eval = model.eval(expr, true);
            return eval.toString();
        }

        private BoolExpr assertHard(Optimize optimizer, BoolExpr assertion, String name) {
            var tracker = createTracker(name);
            optimizer.AssertAndTrack(assertion, tracker);
            return tracker;
        }

        private BoolExpr assertSoft(Optimize optimizer, BoolExpr assertion, String name, int weight, String id) {
            var tracker = createTracker(name);
            var trackerExpr = z3.mkEq(assertion, tracker);

            optimizer.AssertSoft(assertion, weight, id);
            optimizer.Assert(trackerExpr);
            return tracker;
        }

        protected BoolExpr createTracker(String name) {
            return z3.mkBoolConst(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the Java code

```
Z3 ver: Z3 4.11.2.0
Status: SATISFIABLE
a = 6
b = 6
assertion one   = false
assertion two   = false
assertion three = true
assertion four  = true
```

And here is what the CLI outputs

```
sat
(
  (define-fun one () Bool
    (> a 10))
  (define-fun a () Int
    5)
  (define-fun two () Bool
    (< a 6))
  (define-fun four () Bool
    (= a b))
  (define-fun three () Bool
    (< b 8))
  (define-fun b () Int
    5)
)
```

Comment: If I enable incremental optimization, I get the expected answer in Java (a=b=5, assertion two not relaxed).   ```            Params p = z3.mkParams();
            p.add("incremental", true);
            opt.setParameters(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've answered your own question already. The CLI is implicitly incremental. To get the same effect in Java, you have to explicitly set it to be incremental.

If this is a change in behavior, you can report it in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues